# Can the viewing area be judged by UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

Can the viewing area be judged by `UIScrollView`?

There's many `ImageView` in my `UIScrollVer`, I only hope that in the visible region for loading images `UIImageView`.

How can I do?

thanks for any helps!

Comment: Can you explain more? What exactly do you need?

Comment: I think what you want is the content size which determines how much you can scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Just use your image size for the UIImage that holds the image and set that as your content size.

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
self.scrollView.contentSize = myImage.size;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `contentOffset` property of `UIScrollView` shows the current viewing area.